# Docker image run offline

Tags: meteor, mup

I have a problem with image get from mupjs. I'm base on `meteor (v2.10.0)` and `Vue 3`. I get image from server(`digitalocean`) to run locally(`offline`) but container alway restarting

[image]

and use `Mup js (v1.5.10)` for deploy to server.

Log on docker :
[image]

Comment: You'll need to check the log of the container to get a clue why it is failing to start.

Comment: I add the log from docker above, after I checked it.